# When does a DOJO Event gets fired for DOJO Text Inputs

Tags: dojo

When does a DOJO Event gets fired ??

For example if i have  a DOJO Text Box when does it gets fired whether its on onBlur or onkeyup ??

```
<div name="Phone" id="wokPhone" invalidMessage="Please enter phone number"
    dojoType="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox" regExp="^(\(?\+?[0-9]*\)?)?[0-9_\- \(\)]*$" label="  Phone Number :" maxLength="10"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default it fires on the blur/change event, but if you enable intermediateChanges, it will fire for every keyup.

```
<div name="Phone" id="wokPhone" invalidMessage="Please enter phone number"
    dojoType="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox" regExp="^(\(?\+?[0-9]*\)?)?[0-9_\- \(\)]*$"         
    label="  Phone Number :" maxLength="10" intermediateChanges="true">
</div>
```